# How can i generate missing values using table.CreateSet<>(myClass)() in SpecFlow?

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I'm using SpecFlow for the very first time to write tests for my project and I ran into a small problem.

I have the next class:

```cs
public class FancyName
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List <Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to generate this class in my Tests using SpecFlow helpers.

Here is the part of Scenario:

```cs
[...]
When i add some names
    | Name | Countries |
    | UK   | 1         |
    | US   | 2         |
[...]
```

I try to parse it in step definitions like this:

```cs
[When(@"I add some names")]
public void AddNames(Table table)
{
    var names = table.CreateSet<FancyName>();
    [...]
}
```

And I'm running into 2 problems:

1. I do not pass the Guid because a want to generate it like `Guid.NewGuid()` so created object contain `null`
2. I pass countries as sorting but i need to create `List<Country>()`.

I used to try iterate through Table and create `FancyName` objects manually but as I understand it is not SpecFlow way. I tried to look through documentation and wasn't lucky to find proper solution.

May be somebody know the really good way to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the Country type look like?
How should at the end the instances of your types look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table.CreateSet<>` can't perform magic. It can't know that its supposed to create a new Guid for your object, or that its supposed to create a list containing 2 countries. You'll have to create this object yourself I think.

The best way to solve this is to use a `[StepArgumentTransformation]`

something like this:

```
[StepArgumentTransformation]
public List<FancyName> TransformToFancyName(Table table)
{
    //create the list from the table contents
}

[When(@"I add some names")]
public void AddNames(List<FancyName> names)
{
    .. use your FancyNames here
}
```

specflow will call your `StepArgumentTransformation` for any Step which has an argument of `List<FancyName>` as the last parameter and a corresponding table in the feature

Answer (score 9):

The main SpecFlow.Assist author here...

I agree with @sam-holder above that `Table.CreateSet<T>` is not magic, and perhaps the transform is an easier solution in this case.  But Assist does, in deed, have the features needed to do what is asked.  :)

I'd like to explain how.  I see two issues presented as:

1)  How to set the Guid on each record?

2)  How to convert the string value to an array?

For (1), the answer is pretty simple.  You can pass a function to CreateSet that tells the library how to instantiate the object you want to create.  Since you just want to set the Guid, you can do it like so:

```
    table.CreateSet<FancyName>(() => new FancyName { Guid = Guid.NewGuid()});
    // or simpler, table.CreateSet(() => new FancyName { Guid = Guid.NewGuid()});
```

For (2), you'll have to do a little more programming.  You want Assist to know how to convert the string to a list.  To do this, you'll have to create a "value retriever" and register it with Assist.  I was able to do this with the following code:

```
public class CountryRetriever : IValueRetriever
{
    public bool CanRetrieve(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair, Type targetType, Type propertyType)
    {
        return propertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[SpecFlowExample.Country");
    }

    public object Retrieve(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair, Type targetType, Type propertyType)
    {
        return keyValuePair.Value.Split(',')
            .Select(x => new Country {Name = x})
            .ToList();
    }
}

[Binding]
public class Steps
{
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void Setup()
    {
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist.Service.Instance.RegisterValueRetriever(new CountryRetriever());
    }

    [When(@"i add some names")]
    public void WhenIAddSomeNames(Table table)
    {
        var things = table.CreateSet<FancyName>(() => new FancyName { Guid = Guid.NewGuid()});

    }
}
```

Pointing directly at a list like this, especially using a string, is pretty hacky, but this code does work.

The country retriever will announce that it can handle the transformation of a string when it is confronted with a `List<Country>` type.  It then splits the string and creates a list of countries.

SpecFlow starts each test run with value retrievers for most of the base .Net types, but not your `List<Country>`.  To accomodate your type, you'll need to register your new value retriever before every test run.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about something like [Nested Tables?](http://joebuschmann.com/specflow-nested-tables-a-bad-idea/), but according to this post it's a bad idea. It suggests to introduce additional step to populate complex objects.